# XPath search on an attribute value in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, xpath, powershell-4.0

Despite the examples I've seen online, it doesn't seem to be possible to do an XPath search on an attribute value in PowerShell.

```
[xml]$xml = '<a><b><c foo="bar"></c></b></a>'
$xml | select-xml -xpath //c[@foo]  # This returns a node
$xml | select-xml -xpath //c[@foo='bar'] # This does not
```

I've never been so stumped by something so simple.  :-)  How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you quote the xpath it will work fine:

```
[xml]$xml = '<a><b><c foo="bar"></c></b></a>'
$xml | select-xml -xpath "//c[@foo='bar']"
```

<s>This is probably because [`@` is the splat operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx), so it's trying to splat a (non-existant) variable named `$foo`.</s>

Actually that explanation is wrong. It's apparently because of the single quotes.

If you try this:

```
Write-Host //c[@foo='bar']
```

You'll see that the output is:

> ```
> //c[@foo=bar]
> ```

It seems this is because of how PowerShell concatenates strings.