# How to search for an attribute inside the particular tag using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, search, attributes

I need to search the attribute inside the xml. Specifially inside the tag.

Example: I need to search for **result** attribute

```
<root>
    <college>
        <student>
            <course>
                <table></table>
            </course>
        <student>
            <staff>
                <table name="result"></table>
            </staff>
    </college>
    <school>
        <table name="list"></table>
    </school>
</root>
```

The result attribute can be anywhere I to need search that attribute. It is not specially for one xml file. It needs to be applicable for any xml. If result attribute available. It needs to be identified.

How to achieve it

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath search on an attribute value in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36264788/xpath-search-on-an-attribute-value-in-powershell)

Comment: `$xml.SelectNodes("//*")  | ?{$_.name -eq "result"}`

Comment: Thank working fine @iRon

Comment: How to search the result with in the school node only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can express the existence of an attribute with XPath by simply naming it:

```
$xml.SelectNodes('//*[@result]')
```

Comment: How to search the result attribute only with in the school node

Comment: @ArockiaRajV replace `*` with `school`

Comment: How to express the existence of an table?

Comment: `$xml.SelectNodes("//table")` We can use like this but especially I need to search inside the school node. How to achieve that